# Display notifications according to a time schedule

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, schedule

I really need some guidance here. I implemented an alarm manager that triggers a notification service. And it works if I have to display only one notification. But what I need now is a way to display the notifications according to a time schedule (i.e. 11:00, 13:00, 18:20).

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get control at "11:00, 13:00, 18:20", then call `set()` or `setRepeating()` three times, with unique `PendingIntent` objects. The simplest way to get "unique `PendingIntent` objects" is to pass a unique value to second parameter of the factory method (e.g., `getService()`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer CommonsWare. I have the problem that i could have i.e. 20 or even more "times" in the time schedule list. It depends on the user. Wouldn't it be a little too much code for that? Isn't there maybe a better solution? :(
PS i am making a time-table for students so that they can track their class schedule. I want to send the student a notification when a class is about to start.

Comment: @Aksiom: "Wouldn't it be a little too much code for that?" -- that is impossible to answer, as only you know what you think "too much code" means. "Isn't there maybe a better solution?" -- you are welcome to use a single `set()` alarm, for the next upcoming event, which displays a `Notification` and then uses `set()` to set up the next alarm. I suspect that this will be more code.

Comment: Is there maybe a way to detect when the alarm manager goes off and then to set the same alarm manager with a different time? If yes can you please give me a simple example.

Comment: @Aksiom: "Is there maybe a way to detect when the alarm manager goes off" -- your code gets executed already "when the alarm manager goes off". You claimed that you wrote this part already. "and then to set the same alarm manager with a different time?" -- you would do this using the same code that you already have. "If yes can you please give me a simple example" -- since you already wrote all of the necessary code, you do not need an example.

Comment: You mantioned that i should pass a unique value to second parameter of the factory method `getService()`. How can i retrive that value in the service, if it is possible? I would like to change the text of the notification content according to that value. Sorry if this question is stupid, but I am new to alarm managers and the whole concept of services in android.

Comment: @Aksiom: "How can i retrive that value in the service, if it is possible?" -- AFAIK, that's not possible, unless you pass the same value in another way (e.g., as an extra on the `Intent` you wrap in the `PendingIntent`).

Comment: Ok, thank you CommonsWare, you halped me a lot so i will mark your answer as a good answer. I will try to get something working now. Cheers.